# Areal radius, cosmology

Tags: cosmology, spacetime, universe, space-expansion

In cosmology, what areal radius means exactly? Is defined as

\begin{equation}
R(t,r)=a(t) \, r
\end{equation}

Where $a(t)$ is the scale factor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the FLRW metric :
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
ds^2 = dt^2 - a^2(t) \Big( \frac{dr^2}{1 - k \, r^2} + r^2 \, (\, d\vartheta^2 + \sin^2 \!\vartheta \: d\varphi^2) \Big),
\end{equation}
the aera of a sphere centered on the central observer (the one located at radial coordinate $r = 0$) is $A = 4 \pi \, a^2(t) \, r^2$.  Since this expression should be $A = 4 \pi R^2$ as in euclidian geometry, it is natural to define the *aerial radius* as $R(t, r) = a(t) \, r$.  This is just an abstract mathematical definition and doesn't correspond to a physical distance (proper distance to a given point in space, according to the comoving observers).

On a side: Take note that $R = a(t) \, r$ is the *proper distance* (relative to the comoving observers) in the flat space model : $k = 0$.  $R$ isn't the proper distance for $k = \pm \, 1$.